# C# Firebird/DBLinq IQueryable implementation of Single() and SingleOrDefault is broken?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, firebird

For the `DBLinq.Firebird/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` implementation of `SingleOrDefault` we are getting a result that is incorrect

If `TABLE` has more than one record of `CD = 5`, we are expecting this statement to fail:

```
dbContext.GetTable<TABLE>().SingleOrDefault(r => r.CD == 5)
```

The underlying SQL statement that is generated is

```
SELECT FIRST 2  *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (CD == @CD)
```

in this case, this SQL statement does return 2 records, but the `SingleOrDefault(r => r.CD == 5)` is not failing, and it also returns the second record (not sure if it's random or always the second). Single() exhibits the same behaviour.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Which version of the Firebird ADO.net provider are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, we are using version 5.12.1, which is the latest version at this time

Comment: Then I can only suggest that you file a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET